Displaying vertex colors generated by geometry nodes in a viewport
I'm generating some geometry from scratch via geometry nodes. I also create a custom vertex color attribute there. The attribute type is color, has face corner domain and is connected to the group output:

This attribute is then added in the object data properties:

My question is; how to display this color in the viewport solid shading mode?
It works if I apply the geometry nodes modifier and then delete the default vertex color attribute (called "Attribute") that appears alongside my custom attribute. But I don't know how to make this color visible while geometry nodes are alive.

I can do this with shading (material preview, not solid). Whould this count as a solution?

Kinda. I know how to set that up though. I was wondering if there is an easy way to just show this color by default without shader involvement.

Related to that, It'd also be useful if this color can be made to exported into obj as the default vertex color, without needing to apply geo nodes modifier and delete the default "Attribute" colors that seems to appear when geo nodes are not active any more.

If you're trying to view color attributes generated from geometry nodes in solid shading mode, without applying geometry nodes, then you can use the Viewer node.

Geometry Nodes and Modifiers have come a long way to be able to be viewed and even rendered in images. Add a Viewer node to your node tree to show the custom color attribute that you have created. Your default Viewport Overlays should already have color attributes for the Viewer node turned on.

Likewise, the Node Editor that you are using the Viewer node should be open in one of your workspaces to keep the Viewer node active and unhidden.

Thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for.
